# tsc-watch throwing error: "File 'dist/index.js' is a JavaScript file. Did you mean to enable 'allowJs' option?"

Tags: typescript

I have a simple index.ts file I complied with tsc:

```
function printMessage(msg: string): void {
    console.log(`Message: ${msg}`);
}

printMessage("Hello, TypeScript");
```

When I run the command:

```
npx tsc-watch --onsuccess "node dist/index.js"
```

I get the error "File 'dist/index.js' is a JavaScript file. Did you mean to enable the 'allowJs option?" I've tried it with the allowJs option to true but it still generates the same error.

TypeScript version 3.9.7
tsc-watch version 4.2.9

Comment: It looks like it is passing the `dist/index.js` to the compiler.

Answer (score 2):

I worked around this by installing tsc-watch globally:

```
npm intall -g tsc-watch
```

Then I could run the command without npx:

```
tsc-watch --onSuccess "node dist/index.js"
```

Which worked fine now. Looking at your code it seems you are also following the Essential TypeScript book Chapter 5 page 114 in case others will search for these terms.

Still don't understand why the original command doesn't work. As Aluan mentioned in his comment it seems that the index.js file is actually passed to tsc-watch as it complains that it wants to compile a .js file instead of .ts files.

Comment: the global install worked, so I tried installing it locally and then tried using it via package.json like:

`"start: tsc-watch --onSuccess \"node dist/index.js\""`
but got the below error

`error TS5023: Unknown compiler option '--onSucess'.`

not able to understand why the global is working, and local not working!

Answer (score 2):

This problem is caused by the way that PowerShell parses arguments. Here is the escape sequence that will solve the problem:

```
npx tsc-watch --onSuccess "\`"node dist\index.js\`""
```

Those are double quotes and back ticks. The result is that PowerShell passes on the "node dist/index.js" argument without parsing it.

Comment: this works for me on the cli, but I can't get it to work in an npm script. I can't get the escaping right

Answer (score 0):

```
"scripts": {
   "start": "tsc-watch --onSuccess  \"node dist/app.js\"",
```

This works for me in package.json